# Is this efficient use of the is and as operator in a DrawableGameComponent?

Tags: c#, menu, xna

I'm learning to use the as operator, and my goal was to create an option window (non windows form) that can:

Have options added to it (for flexibility, in case I want to use if statements to add menu items)
Be able to display text, textures, or a class (using the classes draw function)
Be controlled through the host GameState

I still haven't added the options for indicating an item is selected, my apologies for not posting a complete work.  I also have not sorted the code into regions yet.  Sorry again!

Is my code (particularly the draw function) properly using the is and as operators properly, from a performance and readability (non spaghetti code) standpoint?

```
public class OptionWindow : DrawableGameComponent
{
    public Dictionary<int, Option> options;
    int selectedOption;
    bool windowLoops;
    Rectangle drawRectangle;
    int spacer;
    int totalItemHeight;
    SpriteFont sf;
    SpriteBatch sb;

    public Rectangle DrawRectangle
    {
        get { return drawRectangle; }
        set { drawRectangle = value; }
    }

    public int SelectedOption
    {
        get { return selectedOption; }
        set
        {
            if (windowLoops)
            {
                if (selectedOption >= options.Count())
                    selectedOption = 0;
                if (selectedOption < 0)
                    selectedOption = options.Count() - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (selectedOption >= options.Count())
                    selectedOption = options.Count() - 1;
                if (selectedOption < 0)
                    selectedOption = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public OptionWindow(Game game, bool windowLoops, SpriteFont sf, Rectangle drawRectangle)
        : base(game)
    {
        options = new Dictionary<int, Option>();
        this.windowLoops = windowLoops;
        this.sf = sf;
        DrawRectangle = new Rectangle(drawRectangle.X, drawRectangle.Y, drawRectangle.Width, drawRectangle.Height);
    }
    public void Add(object option, bool selectable, bool defaultSelection, int height)
    {
        options.Add(options.Count(), new Option(selectable, option, height));
        if (defaultSelection)
            SelectedOption = options.Count() - 1;
        UpdatePositions();
    }
    public void UpdatePositions()
    {
        UpdateTotalItemHeight();
        if (options.Count() - 1 != 0)
            spacer = (drawRectangle.Height - totalItemHeight) / (options.Count() - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < options.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                options[i].Position = new Vector2(drawRectangle.X, drawRectangle.Y);
            else
            {
                options[i].Position = new Vector2(
                    drawRectangle.X,
                    options[i - 1].Position.Y + options[i - 1].Height + spacer);
            }
        }
    }
    public void UpdateTotalItemHeight()
    {
        totalItemHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < options.Count(); i++)
        {
            totalItemHeight += options[i].Height;
        }
    }
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        sb = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        base.LoadContent();
    }
    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < options.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (options[i].OptionObject is string)
                sb.DrawString(sf, options[i].OptionObject as string, options[i].Position, Color.White);
            if (options[i].OptionObject is Texture2D)
                sb.Draw(options[i].OptionObject as Texture2D,
                    new Rectangle(
                        (int)options[i].Position.X,
                        (int)options[i].Position.Y,
                        options[i].Height,
                        (options[i].Height / (options[i].OptionObject as Texture2D).Height) * (options[i].OptionObject as Texture2D).Width),
                        Color.White);
            if (options[i].OptionObject is DisplayObject)
                (options[i].OptionObject as DisplayObject).Draw(gameTime);
        }
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}

public class Option
{
    bool selectable;
    object optionObject;
    int height;
    Vector2 position;
    public bool Selectable
    { 
        get { return selectable; }
        set { selectable = value; }
    }
    public object OptionObject
    {
        get { return optionObject; }
        set { optionObject = value; }
    }
    public int Height
    {
        get { return height; }
        set { height = value; }
    }
    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        set { position = value; }
    }
    public Option(bool selectable, object option, int height)
    {
        Selectable = selectable;
        OptionObject = option;
        Height = height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is never adviseable to use `is` and then `as`. The usual way to go would be to either of the following:

- just use `is` (if you just want to know the type without subsequent casting)
- assign the result of `as` to a variable and check whether that variable is (not) `null`

The code analysis tool [FxCop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6544) helps you find any spots in your code that use `is` and then `as` and warns you because of performance concerns.

Note however that a better approach altogether might be to declare your `OptionObject` property as some abstract class with a `Draw` method. You could then derive a subclass for strings, one for `Texture2D` instances and another one for `DisplayObject` instances and just call `Draw` in your `OptionWindow.Draw` method. This would leave the decision which actual drawing operations to execute up to built-in polymorphism features of the framework.

Comment: So rather than do the drawing "work" within the OptionWindow, I should replace the object OptionObject with a class that can contain multiple types?   Or should I expand on the Option class to do this work?  Which of those two would be more preferable?

Comment: @SoylentGreen: No, not with a class that can "contain multiple types", but with a class from which you derive multiple types. e.g. you'd have one abstract `OptionObjectBase` class with a `Draw` method (that accepts whichever parameters the subclasses *might* need for drawing; possibly the `Option` instance itself), and three subclasses `StringOptionObject`, `Texture2DOptionObject` and `DisplayOptionObject` that store a string, a `Texture2D` or a `DisplayObject`, respectively, and override `Draw` to execute the appropriate drawing operation(s).

Comment: Ah!  I see, so create an abstract base type, and derive everything from it.  After that, my OptionWindow class would only have a for statement that executes options[i].OptionObject.Draw();   Is that accurate?   I really appreciate your input, I'm learning a lot here!

Comment: @SoylentGreen: Yes, exactly :-) That saves you the trouble of selecting the appropriate drawing method yourself and lets you easily extend your code by assigning other subclasses to `OptionObject` later on.